# Calculate growth constant given start, end and number of periods

Tags: calculus, exponential-sum

I'm looking to find a formula for solving for a growth constant, given a known start, end and number of periods.

Best illustrated with an example:

Tom wants to do 10,000 pushups this year. He'll start on day 1 with 1 pushup, and increase X amount each day until he's hit 10,000 for the year.

The increase each day should be constant (e.g., Tom adds 3 pushups a day).

Is there a formula for determining this growth constant?

Thanks!

Comment: How many days should the 10,000 pushups be completed in? 365?

Comment: Yup, let's assume 365 for this example (knowing that this would be a variable that's adjustable, if you wanted to do it just 5 days a week, it'd be 261 days, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be the additional amount of push-ups done each day. Then, after $N$ days, a total of 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{N}(1+kx)
$$
push-ups have been done.
We can simplify this sum as follows:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{N}(1+kx)=\sum_{k=0}^{N}1+x\sum_{k=0}^{N}k=N+x\cdot\frac{N(N+1)}{2}.
$$

Now, suppose you want $M$ push-ups done in total. This means you want

$$
M=N+x\cdot\frac{N(N+1)}{2}\qquad\qquad(*)
$$

Thus, whenever you have two of the three variables $x,N,M$ given, you can solve for the third from $(*)$ as follows:

For example, if you want to do $10000$ push-ups in $365$ days, you have $M=10000$ and $N=365$. Hence, by $(*)$,

$$
10000=365+x66795\implies x=\frac{9635}{66795}\approx 0.144.
$$

Thus, you should do $0.144$ more push-ups each day. Since $1/0.144\approx 7$, you could add an additional push-up once every $7$ days.